# Is there a way that I can put into a barplot the significant variables from regression?

Tags: r, plot, regression

Take mtcars for example:

```
> reg <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp + drat + wt, data = mtcars)
> sigvar <- data.frame(summary(reg)$coef[summary(reg)$coef[,4] <= .05, 4]) #extracts significant variables with p-values
> rownames <- rownames(sig) #extracts the variables only
```

I hope to put the rownames on the x-axis of a barplot and the height of the barplot would be the average of the said rownames. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unclear what you want the heights of the bars to be in the barplot. However:

```
reg = lm(mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp + drat + wt, data = mtcars)
## extracts significant variables with p-values
## note the -1 means you skip the intercept 
sigvar = summary(reg)$coef[-1,4] <= .05
```

If I understand what you want, you want a barplot of the average value of those variables which are significant as the height of your bar. You need to match up the significant variables with the variable names in the data frame

```
i = match(names(sigvar)[sigvar], names(mtcars))
```

`i` now contains the columns of the original data frame that correspond to the significant variable. Unfortunately for the `mtcars` data, this means `mtcars[,i]` only returns one column, so normally I would do something like

```
barplot(sapply(mtcars[,i], mean))
```

but that doesn't do the right thing here because `mtcars[,i]` returns a vector. Let's assume for argument that `i = c(5,6)`, then this will work

```
i = 5:6
barplot(sapply(mtcars[,i], mean))
```